# Команда RC_ICONS не работает

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, icon, qmake

Хочу поставить иконку для приложения, следуя инструкции с http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html создаю иконку, пишу в .pro файлу строку `RC_ICONS = 4.ico`, но команда `RC_ICONS` не подсвечивается, как это делает, к примеру, `DEFINES` и при попытке сборки я получаю `[release/Net_Monitoring_resource_res.o] Error 1`

Comment: Попробуйте записать путь явно через `$$PWD/4.ico`. У меня в проекте `RC_ICONS` тоже не подсвечена, но работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрев полную информацию об ошибке, вкладка *Compile Output*, увидел сообщение о том, что файл не содержал в себе нужных данных. Как оказалось, повредились данные во время конвертирования в ICO формат.